# Java ArrayList: cut off ending on each element

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Method returns ArrayList in this form:

```
[Josh 218.4328329 424324324, Daniel 645.6456456 939438292, James 932.3012930 328492343]
```

But I only need the names, so I want the following:

```
[Josh, Daniel, James]
```

How do I cut off everything after the name (including the space after the name) in each item in this ArrayList? Possible solution to specify that I want to start removing everything on first space in the item?

Thank you

Comment: What are the object types in your `ArrayList`?  Are these Strings?  Objects with fields?

Comment: Assuming the ArrayList is strings, you could simply use `String.split(" ")[0]` for each element in the ArrayList

Comment: Or don't use an ArrayList<String> and instead use object encapsulation to encapsulate all this data in fields, and store THAT object into the ArrayList<MyObject> so you can avoid doing explicitly bounds access issues. Also if your API is returning an ArrayList with strings like that, you should re-do the API to be more extensible by using OOP design to return data that is encapsulated, instead of all serialized to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every object in the list is an object with some fields, then do something like

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for (MyObject object : list) {
   names.add(object.getName());
}
```

That's about as accurate as I can get with the limited details you've provided us.

Answer (score 1):

What did you try to do this so far? Please show some effort in your question.

```
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s: oldList){
 newList.add(s.split(" ")[0]+" "); // Because you want space too
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if the names always appear first, you could try this piece of code:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for (MyObject object : list) {
    names.add(((String) object).split(" ", 0));
}
```